# how to determine runtime for .net core web app

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to migrate an mvc app to a .net core application.  In my mvc app I use Ninject to set up my data sources and the connection strings.  The logic is something like:

```
public static string GetConnectString(IContext context){
      var httpContext = context.Kernel.Get<HttpContextBase>();

      if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["environmentMode"] == "local")
          return DataConnect.LocalConnectString;

      if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["environmentMode"] == "development")
          return DataConnect.StagingConnectString;

      return DataConnect.LiveConnectString;
}
```

This is in my NinjectWebCommon.cs class and called from the RegisterServices method.

So now in .net core I have a Startup.cs with the ConfigureServices method so I can do something like:

```
services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(DataConnect.StagingConnectString));
```

But I'm not sure how to determine the environment - local, staging or live - to provide the correct connect string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration file is the *appsettings.json* and you can have multiple files, like *appsettings.Production.json*  etc, which will be loaded and override settings from the *appsettings.json* .